Check blocked bin in stripe
In the app that I'm working, it use the Stripe iframe to display the stripe form:
const stripe = Stripe("public_key");
// Set up Stripe.js and Elements to use in checkout form
const elements = stripe.elements(options);
  
// Create and mount the Payment Element
const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', params);
paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');
const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');


In the other hand, in our app we have a list of blocked Bins.
So, for each client that wants to make a payment, I have to get the first 6 numbers of the card and the check if that number is in our list of blocked bins.
I understand that it's not safe so for that probably I can't get the number, and I didn't find anything in stripe api doc regarding to this.
Does anyone know if it's possible to do this?

I'd recommend writing to Stripe Support if there is any way to get the BIN. Alternatively, I'd recommend using Radar rules to block the BINs.

I chatted with Stripe but there is nothing to do it seems.
